# Dynamically set frame src using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML  element

```
<frame src="#" title="Content Frame" name="content" id="content" />
```

I want to set it's "src" dynamically using Javascript on page load. How can I do that ?

I  am trying something like;

```
document.getElementById('content2').contentWindow.location = 'xyz_frame.html';
```

But for some reason it is not working..Again it is a  element and not

A Rough code;

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript"> 
function LoadPage(){ 
document.getElementById('content2').src = 'ipad_lrd_frame.html';
}
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="LoadPage()">
<frame id="content2"></frame>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it <frame src="#" title="Content Frame" name="content" id="content"></frame>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work;

```
document.getElementById('content2').src = "url";
```

(Also you have mismatched IDs for the frame and `getElementById` call)

For a `FRAME`, you need a `FRAMESET` which precludes the use of a `BODY`, so;

```
<frameset rows="50%,*" onload="LoadPage();">    
   <frame id="content2"></frame>
   .....
```

**Update:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadPage(){
    document.getElementById('content1').src = "http://www.google.com";
    document.getElementById('content2').src = "http://www.bing.com";
}
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows="50%,*" onload="LoadPage();">    
    <frame src="#" id="content1">    
    <frame src="#" id="content2">                
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Your going to have to show a reduced test case with all the relevant code/markup

Comment: Put the onload="LoadPage();" in body tag

Comment: In case it helps someone else, mine wasn't working as I had onLoad rather than onload. :)

Comment: Works on IE, Firefox and Chrome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would think fetching frames by name would be more suitable:

```
document.getElementsByName('content2')[0].src = 'ipad_lrd_frame.html';
```

Tested it successfully. Ensure your page uses a frameset `doctype` and you do **not** include `body` tags (use `frameset` tags instead). Also note your script type should be `text/javascript`, rather than language "javascript".

Comment: Hi...cool solution by you..only 1 problem though...Works PERFECTLY in firefox...not sure why it is not working in IE...

Comment: And just to add if I alert document.getElementsByName('content')[0].src , it shows the value correctly even in IE i.e. the complete path for 'ipad_lrd_frame.html'...But finally does not show the content inside ipad_lrd_frame.html

Comment: And I have done exactly what you have said; 
1. Used <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

2. No body tag

3. script type is text/javascript

4. Used getElementsByName

Comment: Also an interesting observation in IE; If I set the document.getElementsByName('content')[0].src to http://google.com, it works fine, but if I set it to a local html file 'ipad_lrd_frame.html', it does not display anything...

Comment: @hmthr - So what if you try modifying the src value from '`ipad_lrd_frame.html`' to '`http://mydomain.com/myfilepath/ipad_lrd_frame.html`'?

Comment: Well...for some strange reason, I copied/created new file and is working there...I'll keep you posted and also accept the answer in some time (if there are no further issues)..Thx.

Comment: Great, so it definitely works then :) If you post your complete source code for the index I can try see if there are any errors or conflicts that may be causing the issue, otherwise I really can't help you any further unfortunately...